# list.remove(x): x not in list not understood

Tags: python

I'm beginning to learn Python and I'm trying to create a function that removes vowels from a given string.
This is my Code :

```
def anti_vowel(text):
  li = []
  for l in text:
    li.append(l)
  while 'a' in li:
    li.remove('a')
  while 'A' in li:
    li.remove('A')
  while 'A' in li:
    li.remove('e')
  while 'e' in li:
    li.remove('E')
  while 'E' in li:
    li.remove('i')
  while 'i' in li:
    li.remove('I')
  while 'I' in li:
    li.remove('o')
  while 'o' in li:
    li.remove('O')
  while 'u' in li:
    li.remove('u')
  while 'U' in li:
    li.remove('U')
  return "".join(li)
```

I get the "list.remove(x): x not in list" error when I try to run it.
I know this error's been already asked about here but I didn't really get the answers in those specific cases.
thanks for reading and please help :)

Comment: Seriously? `while 'e' in li:  li.remove('E')` does not give you an idea? In some line your copy-paste-edit flow got out of sync.

Comment: And this is why copy/paste programming is bad.

Comment: BTW, `li = []; for l in text: li.append(l)` can be written as `li = list(text)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def anti_vowel(text):  

  li = ''  
  for l in text:  
     if l.lower() not in 'aeiou':  
        li+=l  
  return li
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating it, just use a generator expresion:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    return "".join(x for x in text if x not in "AEIOUaeiou")


>>> anti_vowel("asldkfoihyoihbiw")
'sldkfhyhbw'
```

You can use loops also:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    li = []
    for l in text:
        if l not in "AEIOUaeiou":
            li.append(li)
    return "".join(li)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some mis-matches in your `while` statement, for example:

```
while 'e' in li:
  li.remove('E')
```

If there is no 'E' but there is an 'e' this will cause a problem.

You either need to go through and make sure they are consistent.

Or you could write a small function to deal  with each vowel:

```
def remove(letters, vowel):
    while vowel in letters:
      letters.remove(vowel)
```

You can then call this for each vowel.

```
def anti_vowel(text):
  li = []
  for l in text:
    li.append(l)

    for vowel in ['a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U']:
        remove(li, vowel)

    return "".join(li)
```

A more Pythonic way would be to pull out the required letters, using a list comprehension or generator, as per the answer from Netware. I'm just pointing out the source of your error.

If you catch yourself repeating something lots, and copy/pasting then tweaking, you can easily miss a few places that need tweaking.
Try to change the repeats into a function.